# How to find an element in a specified range in std::map?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, stdmap

Is there an equivalent version of `std::find(first, last)` but for a `std::map`? I.e., is there a version of `std::map`'s `find` method that searches for an element in a `map`, but restricting the search only to a specified `[first, last)` range? Ideally, the solution should be logarithmic in the size of `[first, last)`.

From [what I've seen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find), `std::map::find` itself doesn't support this functionality (it always searches the whole map).

Comment: May be I am missing something, but why `std::map::lower_bound` is not up to your liking?

Comment: You may want to clarify your `std::find(v.begin(), v.end())` example, to not be calling `begin` and `end`, instead something like `std::find(subrange_first, subrange_last);`. You want something in `O(log(distance(subrange_first, subrange_last)))` not `O(log(size(map)))` nor `O(distance(subrange_first, subrange_last))`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `std::lower_bound`, `std::upper_bound` or `std::equal_range` for that as `std::map` iterators and data in the map satisfy the requirement for those functions, though you should be aware that it will be less efficient than `std::map::find()` due to linear iterator increments.

From `std::lower_bound` [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)

> The number of comparisons performed is logarithmic in the distance between first and last (At most log
>   2(last - first) + O(1) comparisons). However, **for non-LegacyRandomAccessIterators, the number of iterator increments is linear**.

emphasis is mine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, `std::map::lower_bound` is exactly what you are looking for - it gives you the element which is not less than the key. And there is `upper_bound` as well for the other end.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The _search itself_ shall be restricted to `[first, last)` (and be logarithmic in `std::distance(first, last)`), not the returned results. `std::map::lower_bound` is no better than `std::map::find` in that regard.

Comment: @MaxLanghof No, you are wrong. `std::find` will give you the element if it is in the map, while the `lower_bound` will only give you the element if it is not less than the one supplied to lower_bound. You should reconsider your downvote. So it is exactly like `std::find` with boundary.

Comment: Neither of that is what the question asks for. Again, this is about restricting the search range, not about how to find an element in the entire map.

Comment: `std::find` and `std::lower_bound` are both restrictions on search range. You clearly misunderstand the question.

Comment: `std::map::lower_bound` does [not](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) have restrictions on search range. If you want to your answer to be about `std::lower_bound` (not `std::map::lower_bound`) then feel free to change it accordingly (but that is covered by Slava's answer already).

Comment: @MaxLanghof search range vs filtration of sort results is impossible to differentiate for the outside observer. The observed behavior is the same, the method of search is implementation detail.

Comment: The complexity is different. If I have `2^N` elements in the map then searching all of them takes `O(N)`. If I know that my element is in a range `[first, last)` with `std::distance(first, last) == N` then the search should be doable in `O(log(N))`. As explained in Slava's answer, `std::lower_bound` (and friends) allows you to do it in `O(log(N))` comparisons but `O(N)` iterator increments.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I am completely missing your point. Map lookups are O(log N).

Comment: And so is searching in a sorted range (which a `std::map` consists of). The point is that the `N` of the map and the `N` of the range to search can be (very) different. Please look at my example again, where the former is `2^N` and the latter is `N`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof it is still way better than the most upvoted answer with O(N) complexity, so performance wise it is best the OP can hope for, and behavior-wise it is exactly what they need. I stand behind my answer.

Comment: Let me rephrase. I have a map with 1e20 elements. But I know that the element I'm looking for is in the first three. How can I tell the map to search for my element in that tiny range without (binary) searching all 1e20? Your answer is `O(log(elements_in_map))` (comparisons), whereas the accepted answer is `O(length_of_range)` (iterator increments). It should not be hard to see that there are cases where `length_of_range <= log(elements_in_map)` (both my examples detail such cases). Not to mention that iterator increments and comparisons may have very different real costs.

Comment: @MaxLanghof if you have *2^N* elements in the map, then searching among all of them (i.e.,`std::map::lower_bound`) takes *O(N)*, right. However, if you restrict your search to just *N* elements of those *2^N*, `std::lower_bound`/`std::upper_bound` can **not** do that in *log(N)* because `std::map`'s iterators are **not** *random access iterators*.

Comment: @ElProfesor I never said something to the contrary? I clearly specified `O(log(N))` comparisons and `O(N)` iterator increments _when using `std::lower_bound`_ etc., with the _theoretical optimum_ being `O(log(N))` for both. I'm not entirely sure on that theoretical optimum tbh, but I never said that `std::lower_bound` was `O(log(N))` altogether.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Well, not so clear at first glance: *then the search should be doable in `O(log(N))`*, but you are right, since you explained it just after that sentence. Sorry.